# App Store error: The binary you uploaded was invalid

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

The notorious error haunts me in App Store: "The binary you uploaded was invalid. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate."

Steps I've taken:

1) I'm using Monotouch / MonoDevelop. 
2) App works on iPhone Simulator and on Device.
3) I've made the distribution build according to the examples in MonoTouch documentation (using Distribution profile). 
4) I've checked that the xxxx.app package contains the file "embedded.mobileprovision". 
5) I'm zipping (in OS X GUI) the app bundle (only the xxxx.app file).
6) I've checked the integrity of the xxxx.app file with command "codesign -vvvvv xxxx.app"
7) I've cleared all keys and profiles from XCode Organizer and KeyChain, and added keys/profiles again.

No luck.
Any ideas?

/pom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're using a provisioning profile for the App Store (not for Ad Hoc distribution)

Then select this profile when building your app.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with MonoDevelop, but when this kind of thing happens with XCode cleaning out the whole build folder (i.e., manually deleting the files rather than just selecting "Clean" from the menu) and building entirely from scratch usually helps.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution:

1. Revoke Distribution Certificate
2. Create new AppStore provisioning profile

This solved my problem. Spent 4hrs+ :( :)