# Uploading Binary iPhone App "The signature was invalid" again again and again

Tags: iphone, xcode, upload, sdk, signature

I'm going crazy! I'm trying to upload the binary of my first application but I have always the same error!
"The binary you uploaded was invalid. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate."

I did everything, EVERYTHING!!

I created the request for the certificate, used it for both developer and distribution certificate, created the provisioning profile (12 times!!!) always cleaning my keychain and my Xcode deleting the old certificates and profiles..
I reboot the machine, reboot Xcode, the log is correct, but... I can't upload my app!!!!
Checked if my iPhone is connected (i tried with iPhone disconneted too).
I checked the certificate in both my project settings "Distribuition" Configuration (duplicate of "Release" configuration) and in my target settings.
Reveal in finder, compress the app and sent the zip...
I tried with Application Loader and iTunes connect online..
but nothing! NOTHING!!
I've spent 8 hours! And again i can't have my app uploaded!!!
I'm really going crazy!

Can anyone help me pleeease?
Thx!

Comment: Silly comment, but are you 100% sure it is an App Store profile?  And matches the bundle identifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there are a LOT of causes for receiving this cryptic and mostly unhelpful email. Even after verifying the use of distribution certificates, cleaning & rebuilding my project, and checking with codesign from the command line (and following instructions from the email), no errors showed up—-but I'd get the "invalid signature" email right after uploading. All the solutions seem anecdotal and obviously depend on what secret error is causing the problem. I've spent the last week pulling my hair out, trying to figure it out for my app—-and finally got it successfully submitted today—so let me share my story and see if it's relevant to your situation.

In my case, I seemed to have a complex cause of having my Entitlement.plist set with an incorrect variable along with the holdover of an old provisioning profile (from a previous Xcode version?) buried deep in the project.pbxproj component of my Xcode project file.

The "aps-environment" variable in my Entitlements.plist was set to "distribution" instead of "production" (I swear I read somewhere in the developer docs that it was supposed to be "distribution"!) But fixing that alone wasn't enough to get my app through. (I must have submitted 100 different combinations of app configurations trying different variables!) Starting with the [helpful suggestions from this post](http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=9167082#9167082) on another forum, I dug through the distribution profile and found duplicate entries for some variables. The duplicates had empty quotation marks (i.e. nothing set for the variable) or strange variables or old provisioning profiles which seemed to be causing problems (somehow). Cleaning this up and removing the duplicate lines with bad variables worked in my case. YMMV. But carefully examining the project files ("show contents" on the Xcode project file in finder) seems like a good idea for diagnostics. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Been there - done that.

Make sure your certificate is in the "login" keychain, and that that i the default keychain (highlighted bold) in Keychain Access

Make sure you have both the private and public keys for your certificates and that they are valid. You will also need the Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Cert Authority installed.

I assume you have dragged the profile into xcode - easiest to drop them onto the xcode icon on the dock.

Make sure as Paul says, that the bundle identifiers all match up

You say you checked the certificate in the distribution configuration. Its not the certificate you need to concentrate on but the provisioning profile.

Select your Release config top left, click on the project under groups & files and do cmd I. Select build tab and then pick distribution in the top left. Then look at the Code Signing Identity. Pull down the dropdown list and make sure you have the right application identifier, the right profile and the right certificate. Don't use the Automatic Profile Selector.

Hope one of those steps helps!

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when I tried to submit a version update from the Organizer. What solved my issue was using the Application Loader found in the directory /Developer/Applications/Utilities. You'll need to compress your .app file and send the corresponding .zip file. I used this for my initial submission as well, I just thought I'd try the new way. What a pain! Go with Application Loader.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution:

1. Revoke Distribution Certificate
2. Create new AppStore provisioning profile

This solved my problem. Spent 4hrs+  :(  :)

Comment: This is exact duplicate of your [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097143/app-store-error-the-binary-you-uploaded-was-invalid/24838342#24838342). Instead of posting duplicate answers, you should post a single answer and give link here in a comment for the reference.

Comment: added in both thread to..so that if anyone face problem then i helps them..:)

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem. I resolved it, after hair-pulling, by going back into Keychain Access one more time and discovering the "Show Expired Certificates" menu item. When I did that, one more expired cert of the kind I had (so far, unsuccessfully) replaced showed up! I had deleted a couple of expired certs already, but this menu item caused another to show up, and after deleting it, my upload worked. I was previously aware that expired certs can get in the way of valid ones, and I STILL wasted a lot of time. Hopefully, this helps some people.